# NancyFx Pass data from view to module

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, model, nancy

Hi I want to pass some data from an input tag to my module in NancyFx so I can add it to a json file. Looked everywhere for an answer but can't find anything.

**VIEW**

```
@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<model>
@{
    Layout = "Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div id="addUser">
    <form name="addUser" method="POST">
        <p>First Name:</p>
        <input type="text" name="user">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Module**

```
public class LeaderboardModule : NancyModule
{
    public LeaderboardModule()
    {
        Get["/adduser"] = _ =>
            {
                //var leaderboard = new LeaderboardModule();
                //var users = new List<Users>();

                //users = leaderboard.ReadFile("Users.json");

                //users.Add(new Users() { Id = 7, Name = "John" });

                //var lastItem = users.LastOrDefault();

                //leaderboard.WriteFile("Users.json", users);

                return View["Shared/_AddUser"];
        };

        Post["/adduser"] = _ =>
        {
            var leaderboard = new LeaderboardModule();
            var users = new List<Users>();

            users = leaderboard.ReadFile("Users.json");

            users.Add(new Users() { Id = 7, Name = "John" });

            //var lastItem = users.LastOrDefault();

            leaderboard.WriteFile("Users.json", users);

            return View["Leaderboard"];
        };
    }

    public List<Users> ReadFile(string fileName)
    {
        var users = new List<Users>();

        var readFile = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fileName));

        users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Users>>(readFile);

        return users;
    } 

    public string WriteFile(string fileName, List<Users> users)
    {
        var newUser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(users, Formatting.Indented);

        File.WriteAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fileName), newUser);

        return newUser;
    }
```

Here I just hard code the data in but I want to be able to add the data from the input on the view. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assume the data you want to send back is whatever the user typed in the `user` form field. In your `POST` handler you can get to that like this:

```
Post["/adduser"] = _ =>
{  
    var user = Request.From.user;
    // do stuff
    return View["Leaderboard"];
}
```

`Request` is a property on `NancyModule` and `Form` is a property on `Request` of type `DynamicDictionary`. When there are `FORM` field in the `HTTP POST` request they will be accessible in `Request.Form` by the same name as they have on the page.

For small but working check out [this](https://github.com/horsdal/ShortURL/tree/master/ShortUrl), particularly [this line](https://github.com/horsdal/ShortURL/blob/master/ShortUrl/ShortUrlModule.cs#L20).

Comment: Hi Christian. This work, only, if you pass data, from "model to html control (in View)", and then, from "html control to model". Is there a solution, to get all the model (I have many properties, over 20 in my model, and don't want to build many hiddenFields in my View).

Comment: How do you want the HTTP request to look? It doesn't sound like you want POST a Form. But then what? A json body?Something else?

Comment: In my imaginery "perfect world" I would like to have (in one more automated way or another) to have model back from view. It could be a json, or some strange hidden field or whatever.

Comment: It would seem your options are sticking the extra properties in hidden form fields, put them in a json blob on the page and post them back in Ajax request or storing them in a server side session.

Comment: I will keep that in mind, and check it next time. Thx.